# How do you 'incrementally' create vector tiles?

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I am serving my own vector tile layer. In my current setup when a point of interest is added by a user it is stored in PostGis and the relevant zoomtiles are reproduced and written over the previous ones. For high zoomlayers this is fast, however for low zoom (e.g. the world) the processing is demanding as in recreating the vector tiles millions of points of interest are involved.

Is it necessary to 'recalculate' the entire tile? Are there ways to recreate vector tiles in an 'incremental' way which is less processor demanding? This would make sense as the content at lower zooms is >99% the same as the previous vector tile. Does protobuf or other vector tile formats allow such patching? What are existing solutions to my problem?

BTW I am already using a separate tile layer for the points of interest, so it is not like I am recalculating all features. But the points of interest alone can run into millions at world zoom.

Comment: Do you really have millions of points in *one* tile? What is this useful for? Wouldn't you want to group/merge points?

Comment: Is it really necessary to have POIs on that scale? Displaying millions (or even hundreds) of records in a map has no real sense in cartographic point of view.

Comment: @CL Please see next comment...

Comment: @DavidP I understand your questions, but yes from a UX perspective I prefer to have separate points and I purposely do not choose to group / merge. The direction of your questions seems to suggest that 'incremental' changes are not possible!?

Comment: A WMS service with vector tiles should do it I think.  You could also do point clustering on the server end, through the WMS, and only show the actual points when it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @musicformellons my question is: Why to generate tiles with millions of points in low resolutions when there is no real chance how to present them in sensible manner to end user? I would suggest you to generate only resolutions where each tile contains roughly low tenths of points. And no... I do not know how to generate tiles in incremental manner...

Comment: @DavidP Apparently having many points is uncommon. To have an idea of what is the purpose think of it like a kind of 'heat map', a cloud of points, but at the same time having just one isolated point of just one pixel which is not part of a cloud also 'has meaning'.

Comment: @musicformellons it thing that dos not make sense either. Dealing with millions of points on the client-side is a way to hell. You will hit some kind of technological barrier sooner or later (browser capabilities, client hardware, network throughput).

Comment: @DavidP My current solution does work without the issues you bring up. So no hell here. I think it should just be possible to update more quickly. No clear arguments so far why it is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [MVT tile encoding](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1), point coordinates are relative to the coordinates of the previous point. So incremental updates would work only if the changed points happen to be the last ones.

Additions would be easier, but would still require rewriting all arrays inside the tile.

In a tile, the layers are just concatenated. So if your client software can handle this, you could add another layer to the tile (maybe even with the same name).

Comment: If that's the case why not find the previous point and insert the new point after that one and leave other points as is?

Comment: @musicformellons because if you change the geometry of one point in MVT tile, then you change the geometry of all consecutive points in that tile because their geometry is referenced relative to the previous one. So, depends on how many updates you have and where they are located in MVT, most likely, write whole new tile will be faster than update...